# Why is Heisenberg shown dead in Negro y Azul?

Tags: breaking-bad

We see Heisenberg dead at the end of [the music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUmpTKXpIdM) playing at the start of *Breaking Bad* S2:E7.

Is this an incongruity? Maybe a plotline that was ruled out? Or just a bit of fun? I love it but the very end just doesn't seem to make much sense considering how the show plays out with the Cartel.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is just a music video of a [narcocorrido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcocorrido) song explaining that Heisenberg now has a reputation in Mexico and to show how the cartel feels about Heisenberg. If you look closely, the Heisenberg shown isn't even Walter White, but a younger person. The cartel don't know him, their only reference is the drawing.

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: the 'younger person' dressed as Walter is Jesse.

Comment: OK so a threat, not a plot. Great fun fact BTW!